# Object separation using edge information

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I am trying to separate vehicles for counting.

(1)The problem is that if the cars are close in the camera view, it is hard to separate as shown in the first figure.

(2)So I use edge information and I do contour tracing for all connected edge points. If the edge length is longer than threshold then take as real edge. But the problem is sometimes even one vehicle has two or more separate edges as shown in the second figure and how can I make it they are from the same vehicle?

(3) I use corner points as well using `OpenCV's goodFeaturesToTrack`, but no idea how to group them for individual car.

(4)What could be the best way to separate the cars in image processing rather than using edge?

Thanks

[image: first figure].[image]

Comment: How often does this happen? Do you need to have 100% accuracy?

Comment: yes. the higher the better, 100% is my wish. Now my approach is I do foreground/background separation. That results in blobs. Blobs are touching when vehicles are close. Then I am exploring object segmentation techniques to separate the touching blobs. Any other idea?

Comment: A quick-and-dirty heuristic might be to look for convexity defects in each blob. Vehicles would normally be convex shapes, so any significant convexity defect would indicate multiple vehicles needing segmentation or maybe an articulated vehicle (e.g. car towing trailer). Are you tracking these blobs or just analysing snapshots?

Comment: @RogerRowland Thanks. Yes I am tracking. convexity defects is good idea. But I need two steps detection of convexity defects and segmentation. Any faster way?

Comment: I think 100% accuracy is not possible, even with segmentation (imagine two cars of the same colour, side by side). You could quickly refine your estimate by counting the convexity defects - two defects implies two vehicles, three implies three, etc. However, if you're tracking, the blobs shouldn't combine anyway - are you using mean-shift?

Comment: mean-shift is slow in processing. If I detect, convexity defects in blob image then I will separate using separation methods like watershed.

Comment: Did you try to remove the background and apply morphological erosion in the blobs in order to separate them?

Comment: I would use more elaborate techniques, such as detection the vehicles using a Haar cascade and tracking them.

Comment: @GabrielArchanjo Yes I did.So that I can have solid blob.

Comment: @batuman I am also working on the same problem. I am using OpenCV's MOG2 for foreground/background separation and applying morphological operations but i get Blobs of separate vehicles touching each other or the blob of same vehicle is divided in multiple blobs (usually separated in the middle portion of the vehicle). Were you able to solve this problem ? And what approach did you take ?